# Why does my scratch org creation hang forever with a ScratchOrgInfo in New status, when using the Limited Access License?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I've set up an integration into my Dev Hub from a CI server by storing the SFDX Auth URL. The authentication is successful, but when I do `sfdx force:org:create`, my CI job times out at 2 hours without finishing the creation process.

When I check my Dev Hub, I find a `ScratchOrgInfo` object created by the CI system in `New` status, with no error code present.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't follow the setup guide correctly for using the [Free Limited Access License](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/dev_hub_license.htm) to access scratch orgs.

I had added a Permission Set with access to the Scratch Org Info object, but not the Active Scratch Org object. When using this profile, you must grant:

> To give full access to the Dev Hub org, create a permission set that contains these permissions.
>
> - Object Settings > Scratch Org Info > Read, Create, and Delete
> - Object Settings > Active Scratch Org > Read and Delete
> - Object Settings > Namespace Registry > Read (to use a linked namespace in a scratch org)

When the Active Scratch Org permissions are missing, `sfdx`'s polling never completes successfully. Granting this permission solves the issue. Any lingering Scratch Org Info records that remained in New status may safely be deleted.